# What are nulled themes?

Tags: themes, security

In WordPress there is a concept of *"Nulled Themes"*. I searched information about it (on Google) and found some people say it is hacked and others say it is not. I ran the *"iThemes Security"* software over it and everything works without errors.

The Question is:

> Are *"Nulled Themes"* hacked or not secured?
>
> Is "Themekiller" (`http://www.themekiller.me`) a secure website to download a *"Nulled Theme"*?

Comment: Your question is some sort of off-topic, in wordpress.se, we discuss about WordPress development, not its security, webmastering, etc.

Comment: for me the question is answered by @knif3r

Comment: good and very important question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nulled theme basically mean cracked/hacked. The distributors of such themes often hide popups/ads inside to earn money, which you can't see until a user complains about it or you check the website on google speed test for example where you see the image of the website, they aren't secure at all, and it is not worth using them.

Expected behavior of nulled themes and plugins:
Hidden ads/popups/links which benefit the distributor, bad performance in most of the cases, sometimes malware and shells are being injected in the theme, in order to track the information.

Saving 40$ for a theme will waste your time in debugging the nulled theme, living in fear if the developer will take legal actions against you for it, lack of updates, lack of support for it and other features which are theme related and last but not least you support a bad industry and split on many hours of developing a theme.

Simply don't! : )

Comment: That kind of answers I'm looking for.

Thank you very very much

Comment: Also please check [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/241849/should-i-install-plugins-to-my-wordpress-installation-from-web-sites-having-in-u), very related!