# Should I install plugins to my WordPress installation from web sites having in URL "nulled" or, "null"?

Tags: plugins, security, plugin-recommendation

I would like to bring some attention to WordPress people. On few places or Websites you may find some plugins for free that usually cost money. These websites usually have "null" or "nulled" in URL.

Should I install them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is nulled themes](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232041/what-is-nulled-themes)

Comment: @cjbt, those are themes (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232041/what-is-nulled-themes), and in here plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is a security risk. Not only morality question.

I checked some of these plugins and found most of all of these are infected. For instance, they will use `base64encode` functions and evaluate in the end to send info from your web site to URLs in Panama, Iran or like.

They may write to your `license.txt` or `readme.txt` files for instance, and in that way the hackers can get your credentials.

**Note**
There may be honest businesses having "null" or "nulled" in URL so I would like to enclose, since I meant specifically those web sites delivering hacked plugins.